# mongodb:Unexpected token ILLEGAL when using $where in query

Tags: mongodb

in my collection, I have a field called anchorDates which looks like

```
{
    anchorDates: {
        "12345:TS" : "2015-07-16T18:10:15+00:00"
    }
}
```

and i tried a query that use the $where:

```
db.members.find({$where:function(){return this[anchorDates][12345:TS]=="2015-07-16T18:49:04+00:00"}})
```

and it gives an error

```
Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

i also tried

```
db.members.find({$where:function(){return this.anchorDates.12345:TS=="2015-07-16T18:49:04+00:00"}})
```

and get the same error, I thinks its because the colon between 12345 and TS, but have no idea how to query this. Thanks!

Comment: try '12345:TS' with quotes.  db.members.find({$where:function(){return this[anchorDates]['12345:TS']=="2015-07-16T18:49:04+00:00"}})

Comment: @Makoton i tried but have error "$err" : "ReferenceError: anchorDates is not defined\n, i should use function(){return this.anchorDates['12345:TS']} instead, thank you as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the strings if you are using brackets:

```
this['anchorDates']['12345:TS']
```

OR:

```
this.anchorDates['12345:TS']
```

Which in your example would be:

```
db.members.find({$where:function(){return this["anchorDates"]["12345:TS"]=="2015-07-16T18:49:04+00:00"}})
```

But if you can you should be using the more straightforward query:

```
db.members.find({"anchorDates.12345:TS":"2015-07-16T18:49:04+00:00"})
```

Using `$where` is sort of a last resort if none of the other query operators would work. Check out the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! the first one seems doesn't work with error: "$err" : ReferenceError: anchorDates is not defined\n, but the second works fine. Yeah, in this simple case i shouldn't use $where, but i have many more things to add in my code so i have to use, thank you very much!

Comment: @user2810081 Glad it worked for you although I'm not sure how you got that error for the first one as it's just a string and not a variable. That error is for when a program tries to reference an undefined value.